# Setting up subdomains on IIS 7.5, Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, dns, iis, iis-7

I've made two folders on my `D:` disk, `web` and `test`. I've set the default web site to `web` and browsing `http://localhost` works perfectly.

I've added a new site and it is set up with the correct physical path and binding `http test.localhost 80 *(IP address)`.

Now, I want `test` to work as a subdomain like `http://test.localhost`. 
How do I make this magic happen in IIS 7.5?  I've read something about wildcards, but cant find anything related in the manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://test.localhost won't work because than it will try to resolve with a DNS server which won't have a "localhost" root domain so it will fail.

If you only need to test on your localhost, than you can set an alias in your [hosts](http://www.windowsreference.com/windows-7/edit-hosts-file-in-windows-7-windows-vista/) file. Though I would suggest using just one name without a subdomain, like "test", to simplify things.

If you are doing this to test for a public site with a real domain name, than you'll be fine as long as you make sure your DNS entries have an entry for that full domain name (with sub) that points to the same IP address.

Wildcards are for when you want all sub-domains to be processed by a parent domain. Like user1.domain.com and user2.domain.com so you can programmatically deliver different content based on the domain. From your description, this isn't what you need for your case.